# How to execute code the second a checkbox is checked? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

When I usually work with checkboxes, I check to see if the box is checked with the code below:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{    
     Label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

This code is usually attached to a button that sets into motion when it's clicked by the user.  This time, however, I want to do something, like change the color of a label, the very SECOND the checkbox is checked by the user.  That is, I don't want to wait until the user pushes some other button to check if the checkbox is checked in order for the label's color to change.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you have to write code inside CheckedChanged Event of checkBox as below:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
```

Comment: When I'm in debug mode and I check off the checkbox it never takes me to the code inside of the event....So I think I'm not triggering the event even though I only have ONE checkbox on my form, and it's called checkBox1, and it's definitely checked.  My checkbox is on one of the tabs in a TabControl container.  Does this change anything?

Comment: Did you actually attach the event to the checkbox?  You can't just add the code above, you must assign it to the checkbox in question.  Let us know if you don't know how.

Comment: this will solve your problem -> this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_CheckedChanged);

Comment: @MikeH I guess I don't know how.  I'm that much of a beginner that I don't know how to assign it to the checkbox in question.

Comment: @Sudhakar I don't know where to put that snippet.  Where do I put it?

Comment: Nevermind.  I put it after InitializeComponent and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need a [CheckedChanged event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx). That one's for ASP.Net, but there's [a version for winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) as well (and xaml, and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hook up to the CheckChanged event and implement your ideas there?